# Measure of $A(\alpha):=\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: 0\le x_1\le x_2 \le...\le x_n \le \alpha \right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, recurrence-relations

Consider the set

$$A(\alpha):=\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: 0\le x_1\le x_2 \le...\le x_n \le \alpha \right\}$$

is it then possible to determine the volume of this set?

After some trying I obtained a bound on the volume of this set that reads

$$\left\lvert A(\alpha) \right\rvert \le \frac{\alpha^n}{n!},$$

but I did not manage to calculate the volume exactly. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Have you tried in the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$? Then $A(\alpha)$ is a triangle, respectively a tetrahedron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume is given by
$$\int_0^{\alpha}\int_{x_1}^{\alpha}\cdots\int_{x_{n-1}}^{\alpha}dx_n\cdots dx_2dx_1$$
Starting with the inner integral
$$\int_{x_{n-1}}^{\alpha}dx_n=\alpha-x_{n-1},$$
then
$$\int_{x_{n-2}}^{\alpha}\int_{x_{n-1}}^{\alpha}dx_n dx_{n-1}=\frac{(\alpha-x_{n-2})^2}{2},$$
and
$$\int_{x_{n-3}}^{\alpha}\int_{x_{n-2}}^{\alpha}\int_{x_{n-1}}^{\alpha}dx_n dx_{n-1}dx_{n-2}=\frac{(\alpha-x_{n-3})^3}{6}.$$
By induction, it then follows that
$$\int_0^{\alpha}\int_{x_1}^{\alpha}\cdots\int_{x_{n-1}}^{\alpha}dx_n\cdots dx_2dx_1=\frac{\alpha^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: are you missing a power in the final expression?

Comment: Yes, I was. Thank you, I fixed it.